# Configure nginx for mysql remote access

Tags: nginx, mysql

I have a VPS and I'm trying to have remote access to my mysql databases.

I granted root privileges to any IP address

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I commented in the `my.cnf` file, the line

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

I restarted mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

But the next step (all the tutorials around mention as such) involves `iptables` to forward requests from port 3306; and I realise that my VPS doesn't even have `iptables` since `sudo service iptables status` outputs `iptables: unrecognized service`

I could install iptables, but **may I achieve the same with nginx?** That is, this fort forwarding to allow remote access to my mysql databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, Nginx and Netfilter are two completely different things.**

You configured your MySQL database in an alarmingly open manner, which might be dangerous. A better option might be to restrict access to it only from the application (a webserver?), and not the whole Internet. To do so, replace the `%` by the addresses of this client.

You asked about setting additional firewall rules with the `iptables` tool of the Netfilter subsystem, which is good. If the tool is not installed, why not installing it?

Nginx, whoever, is a webserver, which you probably sooner or later need anyway. But it is in no way whatoever a replacement for Netfilter.

Comment: I thought ngnix could make port forwarding